# Cannot update file menu Recent File list Your operating system says [Errrno 13] Premission denied: C:\\Users\\Eigenaar\\.idlerc\\recent-file.Ist

Tags: python

I want to make something in **python**, but this always appears

> Cannot update file menu Recent File list Your operating system says
>   [Errrno 13] Premission denied:
>   C:\Users\Eigenaar\.idlerc\recent-file.Ist
>   Select OK and IDLE will continue without updating.

I read the answers here but nothing works!

Comment: Does this appear everytime you "start" python, or only when you want to make something "in" (running) python?
Maybe someone can help you if you provide further information on what exactly you did, what you tried to do and when the error occured.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. And, yes, it happens every time that I open IDLE.

I have Python 3.6.5 in a folder in Program Files, while the files that I have written are in a folder labeled Python under C:\Users\John\Documents.

I have a hunch that Python wants the files that I have written in a different location, perhaps under C:\Users\John.idlerc?

What do folks think?

JohnR

PS ~ I didn't see on this web page where to find the answers that others wrote to the original inquiry.